# Is it possible to create a custom Apache NiFi processor that saves content in memory and not in the content repository?

Tags: java, apache-nifi, processor, in-memory

I would like to create a custom NiFi processor that takes in data from an external source (say an HTTP POST) and is able to save the content in memory and not in the content repository. The goal here is to have the received content not hit the disks, but rather live in memory for faster performance.

I know that you can configure NiFi to host all content in memory using the `org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.VolatileContentRepository` setting however this is not what I want. I really only want to create a custom flow of data that is handled in memory, while other flows are handled using the standard content repository.

Is this possible? Thanks in advance for your help and time!

Comment: you could put your result into cache that stores data in memory.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I was considering using an in memory database to do something like that however I was interested if there was some sort of mechanism within NiFi that would support that. Looking at the code there doesn't seem to be a way.

Comment: look how handlehttprequest/handlehttpresponse - they are using the in-memory map to handle request/response in async way.

Comment: and distributed cache map - nifi build in mechanism to store data in memory

Comment: Thanks for the great information. The in-memory map you are referencing to the handlehttprequest/handlehttpresponse is the StandardHttpContextMap controller service?

Comment: that's correct.

Comment: So I looked into the handlehttprequest/response processors and even with using the distributed cache map the content is still being written to the content repository unfortunately.

Comment: @ngasw did you find any way to customize the repository? I am looking for the same solution.